# Correct/specific term for renaming/restructuring objects

Tags: data, software

I am developing an app whose main purpose is to display data in tables, lists and graphs.

As such, sometimes I need to rename or restructure some of the data recieved from the backend into a "shape" that the graph library or component can understand. For example:

```
//raw data
const data = {
  dataType: "Precipitation",
  dataPoints: [
    {
      timeStamp: "16363173",
      value: "14"
    },
    {
      timeStamp: "16363453",
      value: "15"
    }
  ]
}

//processed data

const processedData = {
  title: "Precipitation",
  data: [
    xAxis: [
      "16363173",
      "16363453"
    ],
    yAxis: [
      "14",
      "15"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I know which tools to use to do the processing, but I was wondering if a specific term is used for this process. I can imagine "map", "serialize", "adapter" are similar in meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. The specific term for the process of converting data from one form to another is [Data Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation).